# cabal: depend on a package with a specific compilation flag

Tags: haskell, compilation, dependency-management, flags, cabal

Can one specificy in `A.cabal` file that package `A` depends on **package `B` compiled with flag `x`**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not possible, and for a good reason: A compilation flag should not change the public API of a package, so if you find a package that has that behavior, you should contact its maintainer.

Comment: I guess I should contact myself regarding [`splice`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/splice/0.6.0.2/splice.cabal) then :)

[`fdSplice`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/splice/0.6.0.2/doc/html/src/Network-Socket-Splice-Internal.html#fdSplice) turned out to take much longer to start than [`hSplice`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/splice/0.6.0.2/doc/html/src/Network-Socket-Splice-Internal.html#hSplice) which on Linux can be forced with the `portable` flag and is otherwise default on other OSes.

Comment: The fact that you're using a `Fd` is an implementation detail. You should probably use [`handleToFd`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/unix/latest/doc/html/System-Posix-IO-ByteString.html#v:handleToFd), and use conditional compilation in your `.cabal` with `if os(linux)\n CPP-Options: -DLINUX`, and `#if LINUX` around the Linux-specific bits in your code. Also, is [`splice(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/splice) actually Linux-specific? I don't think so...

Comment: both `fdSplice` and `hSplice` are actually used indirectly via [`splice`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/splice/0.6.0.2/doc/html/Network-Socket-Splice.html#v:splice) so the implementation details although exported stay kind of away from users unless they want.

Comment: as for splice back then when I wrote the library I could not find anything similar in other OSes. I also expect something similar to be available though, the naming of the namespace `System.IO.Splice.Linux` shows other implementations in other OSes which I am still to find or be told of by somoeone :)